# How to open flow created page in edit mode when flow is embedded in VF page?

Tags: flow, embedded

I can redirect to the created page in detail but I can't redirect to it and have it be in edit mode when presented to the user.  Is that possible?

Comment: do you want to open page in Edit mode or is it related to the flow? If it is the page append a /e after the ID in the URL and set the returl param to the ID of the object( if required). https://na14.salesforce.com/someid/e?retURL=somid%2F

Comment: I tried this:                                                                                              PageReference send = new PageReference('/'  + returnId + '/e?retURL=%2' + returnId);   and thought the resulting URL opens in edit mode if I paste it into my browser I get an error when the code runs.

Comment: its %2F and try just appending /e first then add the retURL param

Comment: Here is all my code:

Comment: <apex:page standardcontroller="CRM_Equip_Req__c" extensions="CRM_EquipReqController">
 <apex:messages />
  <flow:interview name="Equipment_Order_Account" interview="{!myEOAAutoFlow}" finishLocation="{!nextPage}" >
      <apex:param name="currentUserId" value="{!$User.Id}"/>
      <apex:param name="currentUserName" value="{!$User.Full_Name__c}"/>
  </flow:interview>
       
</apex:page>

Comment: are u able to redirect to the edit page with /e param (or) getting errors. I do not have much experience with flows. I can manage things with VF page

Comment: public with sharing class CRM_EquipReqController {
//declarations
public PageReference getnextPage(){
    if(myEOAAutoFlow != null) {
        returnId = myEOAAutoFlow.RequestID;                      
    }
    PageReference send = new PageReference('/'  + returnId + '/e?retURL='%2' + returnId);  
   send.setRedirect(true);
    return send;
}
    private String getEOAccountId() {
        if (myEOAAutoFlow==null) return '';
        else{
          return myEOAAutoFlow.AccountID;     
        }

Comment: PageReference send = new PageReference('/' + returnId + '/e?retURL='%2' + returnId);  gives the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17788/discussion-between-rao-and-kathy).

Comment: the answer = PageReference send = new PageReference('/' + returnId + '/e) and the new flow created doc open in edit mode at the end of the flow using the controller.